# Access the frame of a resized UIImage in a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, resize, uiimage

I set an UIImage in a UIImageView, with contentMode AspectToFit. How can I acces the frame of the **resized displayed UIImage** ? because imageView.image.size.width gives the original width of the image, not the resized width.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property `frame` of `UIImageView` will return the frame of the displayed image.

If you want change frame you should just set new `CGRect frame` to your `UIImageView`

For example:

```
UIImageView *imgView;
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
```

Updated:

To calculate new size you can use following code:

```
UIImage *img;
UIImageView *iView;    
double widthRatio = img.size.width/iView.frame.size.width;
double heightRatio = img.size.height/iView.frame.size.height;
double ratio = widthRatio>heightRatio?widthRatio:heightRatio;
CGSize newImageSize;
newImageSize.width = img.size.width/ratio;
newImageSize.height = img.size.height/ratio;
```

Comment: i know, i'm looking for the newWidht and the newHeight (of the resized image)

Comment: `UIImageView.frame` will give you size of `resized image`

Comment: that's what I just did. It confirms my idea !